# How to trigger a minicart update after adding to cart

Tags: magento2

I have the following class i am using to test adding to cart in a custom way;

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

class Add extends Action\Action
{
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        Cart $cart
    ){
        $this->cart = $cart;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->cart->addProductsByIds([1])
            ->save();
    }
}
```

This works great. When you view the cart it shows my item, all looks cool in the database etc. However, the minicart still shows as if there are no items in the basket.

If i then add another product to the cart using the "add to cart" button on the product or listing pages it adds to the cart and updates the minicart to show both items.

Where does it trigger the minicart to update itself or how does the minicart know it needs to refresh?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Thanks for your help :)

I have found how to trigger it, you need to set up a `sections.xml` inside etc/frontend of your module that tells Magento which sections to update for a given Ajax call. Here is an example;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="[frontName]/[ActionPath]/[ActionName]">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

After my Ajax call has finished to `[frontName]/[ActionPath]/[ActionName]` Magento makes another call to /customer/section/load passing the sections to load.

By default it requests any messages but if you have set up your sections.xml correctly you will also see the section names you have defined in there as well.

Comment: @smartic,Good information i got clew from here

Comment: Please help with http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166641/magento-2-update-quote-cart-value-after-advanced-pricing-changed

Comment: Awesome, I was working on updating other blocks via ajax and this got me there. Thanks for posting your solution.

Comment: @Smartie is there any way to update cart section after some magento api call?

Comment: @Smartie For multiple adding products, it is only updating quantity of first product and rest product count is not shown in mini cart.
Do we nee d to add anything more here?

Comment: I have tried this solution but didn't work for me. My action url is southlincprotection/Index/Index

Comment: As mentioned by @DEEPJOSHI, while adding multiple products to the cart, only first product quantity is displaying in the minicart.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't directly related to the question, but if you are updating the cart via AJAX calls in normal Magento `require.js` files, you can require the `Magento_Customer/js/customer-data` object and ask the minicart to refresh this way, as well:

```
<script>
    require([
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ], function (customerData) {
        var sections = ['cart'];
        customerData.invalidate(sections);
        customerData.reload(sections, true);
    });
</script>
```

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5621

Comment: So i made it here looking for a solution for my custom page_layout. My mini cart count was always 0 whenever i went to any of my custom pages. I ended up having to run `customerData.invalidate(sections);` and then Magento was able to do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

In storefront
if you dive in source in minicart area

```
<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
  <a class="action showcart" 
   data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
     ... 
  </a>

   <script type="text/x-magento-init">
   {
    "[data-block='minicart']": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {"components":{....}
     }
   }
</script>
</div>
```

As you can see here magento2 execute components inside script tag and dynamic bind data to block minicart use knockoutJs

Somethings interesting i discover

```
\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\default.xml
```

From Checkout layout. It define a `component` for minicart-content to getdata
Continue see `Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart` you will see

```
.....
$('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentLoading', function(event) {
      addToCartCalls++;
      self.isLoading(true);
});
.....
```