# Magento2: Custom update cart

Tags: magento2, cart, custom

i have create my custom add to cart controller my cart update but mini cart not update this is my code

```
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();    
   $request = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http'); 
   $resultJsonFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory'); 
   $resultJson = $resultJsonFactory->create();
   $product_id = $request->getParam('product_id');
   $product_qty = $request->getParam('product_qty');

    $id = $product_id;
    $qty = $product_qty;
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
    $listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
    $cart = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
    $http = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
    $session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
    $cart->addProduct($product,array('qty' => $qty));
    $cart->save();

    if($session->setCartWasUpdated(true))
    {
        $response="success";
    }
    else
    {
        $response = "fail";
    }
    $http->setRedirect('checkout/cart/index')->sendResponse();
    return $resultJson->setData(['success' => $response]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create sections.xml file inside your Module:

Path: [Vendor][Modul]\etc\frontend\sections.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="[Modul]/cartaction/add">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="messages"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

Action Name : Your custom addtocart controller.

Comment: i already done let check again

Comment: ontroller\Index\Ajax this is my controller name

Comment: <Action name="your_moduleName\Index\Ajax"> After Complete your action cart section & message section will be triggered.

Comment: You no need to redirect page after your controller success.  $http->setRedirect('checkout/cart/index')->sendResponse(); commend this line and try my fix.

Comment: acctually i am getting addto cart respose in ajax

Comment: so page not refresh without refresh i need

Comment: Refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98869/how-to-trigger-a-minicart-update-after-adding-to-cart

Comment: {"messages":{"messages":[],"data_id":1525277596}} this alwas shows like that