# Customer sections (i.e. mini cart) updated on product page but not on category page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, frontend

I work with a customized Luma theme where the product list has "add to cart" forms just like the product pages.

If I add a product to the cart from the regular product page, the mini cart gets updated correctly, via AJAX request to `/customer/section/load/?sections=cart%2Cmessages&update_section_id=false&_=1482159535255`

If I add a product to the cart from the category listing, the mini cart does not get updated and no AJAX request to `customer/section/load` is triggered.

The script from `section-config.phtml` is present on both pages without difference:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{"*":{"Magento_Customer\/js\/section-config":{"sections":{"stores\/store\/switch":"*","directory\/currency\/switch":"*","customer\/account\/logout":"*","customer\/account\/loginpost":"*","customer\/account\/createpost":"*","customer\/ajax\/login":["checkout-data","cart"],"*":["messages"],"catalog\/product_compare\/add":["compare-products"],"catalog\/product_compare\/remove":["compare-products"],"catalog\/product_compare\/clear":["compare-products"],"sales\/guest\/reorder":["cart"],"sales\/order\/reorder":["cart"],"checkout\/cart\/add":["cart"],"checkout\/cart\/delete":["cart"],"checkout\/cart\/updatepost":["cart"],"checkout\/cart\/updateitemoptions":["cart"],"checkout\/cart\/couponpost":["cart"],"checkout\/cart\/estimatepost":["cart"],"checkout\/cart\/estimateupdatepost":["cart"],"checkout\/onepage\/saveorder":["cart","checkout-data","last-ordered-items"],"checkout\/sidebar\/removeitem":["cart"],"checkout\/sidebar\/updateitemqty":["cart"],"rest\/*\/v1\/carts\/*\/payment-information":["cart","checkout-data","last-ordered-items"],"rest\/*\/v1\/guest-carts\/*\/payment-information":["cart","checkout-data"],"rest\/*\/v1\/guest-carts\/*\/selected-payment-method":["cart","checkout-data"],"rest\/*\/v1\/carts\/*\/selected-payment-method":["cart","checkout-data"],"multishipping\/checkout\/overviewpost":["cart"],"paypal\/express\/placeorder":["cart","checkout-data"],"paypal\/payflowexpress\/placeorder":["cart","checkout-data"],"review\/product\/post":["review"],"authorizenet\/directpost_payment\/place":["cart","checkout-data"],"braintree\/paypal\/placeorder":["cart","checkout-data"],"wishlist\/index\/add":["wishlist"],"wishlist\/index\/remove":["wishlist"],"wishlist\/index\/updateitemoptions":["wishlist"],"wishlist\/index\/update":["wishlist"],"wishlist\/index\/cart":["wishlist","cart"],"wishlist\/index\/fromcart":["wishlist","cart"],"wishlist\/index\/allcart":["wishlist","cart"],"wishlist\/shared\/allcart":["wishlist","cart"],"wishlist\/shared\/cart":["cart"]},"clientSideSections":["checkout-data"],"baseUrls":["http:\/\/******\/"]}}}</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution while writing down the details, now I'll leave it here, because others might have the same problem:

My custom "add to cart" form on the category page used "GET" instead of "POST". This works well in terms of adding the product to the cart, but customer sections only react to modification requests, i.e. POST, PUT, DELETE, as described in [Magento 2: how do customer sections / sections.xml work?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112948/magento-2-how-do-customer-sections-sections-xml-work)