# How to get customer email from javascript?

Tags: magento-2.1

I need to get the customer email in homepage in a script.

Googling around I find mentions of `window.customerData` variable, but is always undefined (perhaps removed in latest versions?)

So at first I tried this:

```
require([
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
...
```

but it fails with error:`TypeError: can't convert undefined to object` somewhere in `customer-addresses.js`

Then I tried with:

```
require([
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
...
```

and then `customerData.get('customer')` but it gives me only first and last name or an empty object (even when the user is logged).

Is there a way to obtain the logged user email anywhere outside the checkout page?

Comment: have you find a way to retrieve customer email via js?

Comment: @LucaS Not out of the box. I ended up creating a new section to be called from `customerData.get('myCustomSection')` with the info I needed.

Comment: great, i need to retrieve it too, could you answer with your entire solution?

Comment: @LucaS probably this will help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112948/magento-2-how-do-customer-sections-sections-xml-work

Comment: sure thx! but your question remains open try to close it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a plugin in order to save customer email to the local storage. So, add a frontend plugin configuration in `di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\Customer">
        <plugin name="additional_section_data" type="Your\Module\Plugin\AddCustomerEmail" />
    </type>
</config>
```

And the plugin will look like this:

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer;

class AddCustomerEmail
{
    /**
     * @var CurrentCustomer
     */
    private $currentCustomer;

    public function __construct(
        CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer
    ) {
        $this->currentCustomer = $currentCustomer;
    }

    public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Customer\CustomerData\Customer $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($this->currentCustomer->getCustomerId()) {
            $customer = $this->currentCustomer->getCustomer();
            $result['email'] = $customer->getEmail();
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

More information can be found in a similar question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157227/magento-2-get-customer-lastname-in-header-phtml).

Comment: Thank you, I ended up by doing something very similar: a custom data section.