# Magento 2: get customer().lastname in header.phtml

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, header

I don't get how this works. I'm trying to edit the header of my Magento 2 store (`Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml`) and I'm trying to retrieve my customers lastname like this:

```
<span data-bind="text: new String('<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome %1', '%1'));?>').replace('%1', customer().lastname)"></span>
```

It works fine when it says 'fullname' instead of lastname: this shows my full name. It also works fine when I replace it with 'firstname': this shows my first name. Why doesn't it work with last name and what is the right way to get all the customer data here?

Answer (score 8):

**TLDR;**

You need to create a plugin in a custom module to override the `Magento\Customer\CustomerData\Customer` class. In your module's di.xml file:

*app/code/Vendor/LastName/Plugin/etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\Customer">
        <plugin name="vendor_lastnameplugin"
                type="Vendor\LastName\Plugin\CustomerData\Customer"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And then in your override file:

*app/code/Vendor/LastName/Plugin/CustomerData/Customer.php*

```
<?php
namespace ForeverNew\Criteo\Plugin\CustomerData;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer;

class Customer
{
    protected $currentCustomer;

    public function __construct(
        CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer
    ) {
        $this->currentCustomer = $currentCustomer;
    }

    public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Customer\CustomerData\Customer $subject, $result)
    {
        $customer = $this->currentCustomer->getCustomer();
        $result['lastname'] = $customer->getLastname();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

This will create a `customer().lastname` for you to use in your template file.

**More Background**

There isn't a `customer().lastname`, and it's a bit convoluted as to how to add that in. The template (magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml) is calling in the customer component with this script:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "customer": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But looking that file (after all the preamble) you will find only this line:

```
this.customer = customerData.get('customer');
```

But even following that call, you still don't get to the right file you need to edit. Turns out that the array that is defining the values for the `customer()` element is coming from a php file that is populating an array that is then getting used to define these values:

*vendor/magento/module-customer/CustomerData/Customer.php*

```
public function getSectionData()
{
    if (!$this->currentCustomer->getCustomerId()) {
        return [];
    }
    $customer = $this->currentCustomer->getCustomer();
    return [
        'fullname' => $this->customerViewHelper->getCustomerName($customer),
        'firstname' => $customer->getFirstname(),
    ];
}
```

Adding into the return array will add in any value that you can then access in the knockout template with dot notation, i.e. `customer().anythingYouWant`. So in this case you need to create a plugin to add to the return array with that value populated. It's just by luck that you already have access to `$customer->getLastname()` in that class, so you don't have to import any other class or data to get what you are looking for.

As a side note, this is a pain to test in the browser. Since the data that is set here is stored in the session, you have to clear that when testing out values. If `customer().lastname` is set, even if you change it in the php, the value that is set will persist. So you can log out or just clear `mage-cache-storage` in the browser and go on with your day.

Comment: I was trying to get Customer group Id by `'groupId' => $customer->getGroupId()` but it doesn't work, any idea where to go from there? ( I know it works elsewhere by using `$block->escapeHtml($block->getCustomer()->getGroupId()` )

Comment: `$subject->currentCustomer` is a protected property. Try injecting `Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer` in the constructor, then use `$customer = $this->currentCustomer->getCustomer();` in the `afterGetSectionData` method.

Answer (score 4):

Completely no need to add tons of backend plugins here... Just initiate JS on your span with

```
<span data-mage-init='{"js/customerGreeting":{}}'>
```

and in your theme in `web/js/customerGreeting.js`

```
define([
    "jquery", "Magento_Customer/js/customer-data"
], function($, customerData) {
    "use strict";
    return function (config, element) {
        var firstname = customerData.get('customer')().firstname;
        if (typeof (firstname) === "undefined") {
            customerData
               .reload('customer')
               .then(function() { 
                  const firstname = customerData.get('customer')().firstname;
                  if (firstname) {
                    $(element).text('Hi, ' + firstname); 
                  }
               });
        }
    };
});
```

If you want just last name, you can extract it via regex or `split(' ')`

Comment: `reload` returns a Promise, so you can skip the `setInterval` logic and replace it with `customerData.reload('customer').then(function() { customerData.get('customer')().firstname; })`

The `setInterval` method will have code on the page running every half-second until firstname comes back. Or forever if the web request fails for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

for me it didn't worked like that, instead to get the Customer Name,
I used the following code:

`echo   $customerSession->getCustomerData()->getFirstname();`

if anyone finds this useful.

Comment: I used Shoaib Rehman Answer with this one inside if condition.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to create a object instance:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

& then try this:

```
    <?php
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) { 
            echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName()."<br/>";  // get  Full Name 
            echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getFirstname()."<br/>";  // get Customer First name
            echo   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getLastname()."<br/>";  // get  Last Name
        }    
    ?>
```

Comment: getLastName still doesn't show the last name. It appears to be empty. Also I'm still wondering why this doesn't seem to be working through databindings.

Comment: never user object manager in templates.

Answer (score -1):

In your PHP file do:

```
protected $_customerSession;
protected $_customer;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customer,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession->create();
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getCustomerLastName(){
    if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
        return $this->_customer->getCustomerData()->getLastName();
    }
}
```

And then in your phtml file you can simply call the function by doing:

```
$blockObj = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Company\Module\Block\Index\FileName');
$blockObj->getCustomerLastName();
```

This will check if the user if logged in. And if so then it will pull their last name.