# How to render HTML with AJAX in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, ajax, best-practice, page-layouts

I try to find the best way to render HTML through AJAX in Magento 2.

**Way 1 : Using Controller without layout**

File `Foo/Bar/Controller/Popin/Content.php`

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bar\Controller\Popin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

/**
 * Class Content
 */
class Content extends Action
{

    /**
     * Content constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Layout $layout */
        $layout = $this->_view->getLayout();

        /** @var \Foo\Bar\Block\Popin\Content $block */
        $block = $layout->createBlock(\Foo\Bar\Block\Popin\Content::class);
        $block->setTemplate('Foo_Bar::popin/content.phtml');

        $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
    }
}
```

---

**Way 2 : Using Controller with custom layout**

File `Foo/Bar/Controller/Popin/Content.php`

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bar\Controller\Popin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

/**
 * Class Content
 */
class Content extends Action
{

    /**
     * Content constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

File `Foo/Bar/view/frontend/page_layout/ajax-empty.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <container name="root"/>
</layout>
```

File `Foo/Bar/view/frontend/layout/foo_bar_popin_content.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="ajax-empty" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="root">
            <block class="Foo\Bar\Block\Popin\Content" name="foo_bar_popin_content" template="Foo_Bar::popin/content.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

---

IMO the best practice seems to be the **Way 2** because it separate the logic from the Controller.
But the issue with the **Way 2** is that the `<body>` and `<head>` with `CSS` / `JS` are generated so it is not a full cleaned HTML with only my block template in it.

- am I using the custom layout the wrong way ?
- Is the **Way 1** is considered as a good practice ?
- Are there any others ways to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my example I can not use `sections` because it is not `customer data` and it is not after a `PUT` / `POST` action but using `Raphael at Digital Pianism` answer I figured out how Magento render sections.

If we take the example of `cart` section it use the method `\Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPool::getSectionDataByNames` to retrieve data from sections. This lead us to `\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart::getSectionData` with a single array containing areas of the section, including `$this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons')->toHtml()`

Depending on that here is the final Controller class:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bar\Controller\Popin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class Content
 */
class Content extends Action
{

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    private $logger;
    /**
     * @var Validator $formKeyValidator
     */
    private $formKeyValidator;
    /**
     * @var JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     */
    private $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * Content constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        Validator $formKeyValidator,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->logger            = $logger;
        $this->formKeyValidator  = $formKeyValidator;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart/');
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
        $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

        try {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Layout $layout */
            $layout = $this->_view->getLayout();
            /** @var \Foo\Bar\Block\Popin\Content $block */
            $block = $layout->createBlock(\Foo\Bar\Block\Popin\Content::class);
            /** @var array $response */
            $response = [
                'content' => $block->toHtml(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $resultJson->setStatusHeader(
                \Zend\Http\Response::STATUS_CODE_400,
                \Zend\Http\AbstractMessage::VERSION_11,
                'Bad Request'
            );
            /** @var array $response */
            $response = [
                'message' => __('An error occurred')
            ];
            $this->logger->critical($exception);
        }

        return $resultJson->setData($response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

I would also go the way 2 and, indeed, you actually can render "pure" HTML via AJAX without the head, body, css and so on.

The trick is to:

- tell your controller to instanciate a Response that is of type `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout` rather than `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page`
- use a layout XML file with a root node that is `<layout...>...</layout>` rather than `<page...>...</page>`

Here is a very simple implementation.

### The controller

```
<?php    
namespace Namespace\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * Dispatch request
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_LAYOUT);
    }
}
```

### The layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Some\Block" name="namespace_module.some_block" />
    </container>
</layout>
```

### Example on Github

See this example module: https://github.com/herveguetin/Herve_AjaxLayout_M2

This module generates this:

[image]

Comment: What If I want load whole layout (XML with few containers, block etc)? create -> toHtml, and send via json to ajax?

Answer (score 5):

Out of the box, Magento does not use any of those methods to render HTML via AJAX.

From what I've seen, everytime such thing needs to be done, JSON is used to transport the result.

Example from the `Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add` :

```
$this->getResponse()->representJson(
    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($result)
);
```

Then Magento 2 uses a new mechanism called sections, to handle the data on the frontend and update the specific blocks that need to be updated, you can learn more about sections in this Q&A: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/143381/2380

EDIT regarding the second part of my answer: as stated by Max in the comment, sections are only used with customer specific data and using this functionality instead of every AJAX call is not the right solution.

Comment: Yes I also use JSON  to transport the result but I simplify my classes for the purpose of the question ;) But I am not aware of that section feature, it seems to be the right way to do what I want. I will take a look at it. I'll wait if there is any other response otherwise I'll validate your answer. Thanks !

Comment: I agree with using Json response instead of raw html data. But second part of your answer is not full correct. Note, that customer sections using only for customer-specific data and using this functionality instead of every Ajax call is not good idea.

Comment: @MaxStsepantsevich yes in my case I don't want to trigger an refresh after a PUT / POST action but I triggered it by a simple click but Raphael's answer give me hint on how Magento render that parts. It use the **Way 1** that I discribed in my question in `\Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPool::getSectionDataByNames` but it is the same logic. I will make a answer in that way.

Comment: @Matthéo yes, i understood :) My comment addressed to Raphael for correcting answer, because second part of answer can be misunderstood by other users.

Comment: @MaxStsepantsevich thanks for spotting that, I've edited my answer to reflect what you've said

Comment: I added an answer using your feedbacks. Thanks you two for your help.

Comment: Actually Magento (2.1.4) does use the second way in the `Magento_Review` module. See `vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/layout/review_product_listajax.xml` and `\Magento\Review\Controller\Product\ListAjax`. I have posted an answer that extracts the main logic and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $viewModel = $this->_objectManager->get(\Training\CookieConsent\ViewModel\ManageCookies::class);

    $layoutFactory = $this->_objectManager->get(LayoutFactory::class);
    $output = $layoutFactory->create()
        ->createBlock(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::class)
        ->setViewModel($viewModel)
        ->setTemplate('Training_CookieConsent::manage-cookies.phtml')
        ->toHtml();

    /** @var Raw $rawResult */
    $rawResult = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);
    return $rawResult->setContents($output);
```

I copied this from [here](https://technicallysound.in/return-raw-html-results-from-magento-2-controllers/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a heredoc, which supports variable interpolation:

```
function TestBlockHTML ($replStr) {
return <<<HTML
    <html>
    <body><h1>{$replStr}</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
HTML;
}
```