# Render template without layout. Just html code

Tags: magento2

My layout code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">
                <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                            <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                            <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.tier" after="product.info.price">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
                        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <container name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" label="Alert Urls" after="product.price.tier"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
                    <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                    </container>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                            </block>
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Which is giving me out put like this

[image]

On the other phtml file i want to load from ajax and just need the selected area to be render without layout. Just the phtml code as ajax response.

Currently i am getting this

[image]

Please help me. How can i load block and phtml output (html + JS) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a controller to render block logic as json

Then load json via xhr request using jquery

Here is an example of what your controller should look like

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/156229/70343