# Url in Magento2?

Tags: magento2.2

I want to save **customer navigation url** using  `<event name "controller  _front_send_response_before">`.`

But,I can get customer current url and also this `http://localhost/magento2/customer/section/load/?sections=messages&update_section_id=true&_=1513233876606` url.

But I want to get only current url.How to avoid that url.

What can I do?

If anyone knows please explain me?

Comment: Can You provide more details @Mahalakshmi M

Comment: which code you are using now?

Comment: use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
 $currentUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();

Comment: just tried with $block->getCurrentUrl() in template file

Comment: I don't use template file.only use model and observer files

Comment: do you want route,controller and action name only ?

Comment: Please refer this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156425/how-to-prevent-customer-section-load-ajax-call-when-ever-im-making-my-custom-aj