# How to call customerData js in phtml on a specific page after page load

Tags: magento2.2, javascript, knockoutjs, customer-data

I need to call some js in a phtml file only on product details page. I need to check some customer attribute there and show a popup accordingly.

The issue I am facing is that somehow I am unable to get details from customerData on page load and it seems as if my js is loaded before the page loads.

I added setTimeout and after that everything works perfectly.

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block name="trail.user.info" template="Test_TrialuserRestriction::trialuserinfo.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

**trialuserinfo.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'domReady!', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function($, domready, customerData){
    'use strict';

     // Uncommenting this not works for me
    // var customer = customerData.get('customer');
    // console.log(customer().firstname);

    //This works for me when I add timeout
    setTimeout(function(){
        var customer = customerData.get('customer');
        console.log(customer().firstname);
    }, 5000);

})
```

[Edit]

Also tried including the js file using require-config.js but still same.

Any help please.

Comment: Also tried using require js but still same.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is in need of a better and working solution, here you go.

[Magento2 RequireJS CustomerData is empty at page load, but populated once page finishes loading?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210882/magento2-requirejs-customerdata-is-empty-at-page-load-but-populated-once-page-f)

http://slides.yireo.com/yireo/m2_private_content#1

Comment: This solution is exactly the same as your (and mine) not working solution.