# How to get customerData in js uiComponent asynchronously?

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, uicomponent

This is the usual way to get *customerData* on frontend.

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.firstname = customerData.get('customer')().firstname;
        }
    });
});
```

Problem: oth the first load of the page, when *mage-cache-storage* in local storage is cleared, `customerData.get('customer')().firstname` returns undefined. And at this moment, request to server is sent, but js doesn't wait for the response, and the variable is undefined.

I guess it has to be done asynchronously. But how to do it correctly?

I have found these stack questions, but the solutions are the same as mine. Am I missing something?

1. [How to call customerData js in phtml on a specific page after page load](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290227/how-to-call-customerdata-js-in-phtml-on-a-specific-page-after-page-load)
2. [Magento2 RequireJS CustomerData is empty at page load, but populated once page finishes loading?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210882/magento2-requirejs-customerdata-is-empty-at-page-load-but-populated-once-page-f)
3. [GitHub: Magento_Customer/js/customer-data empty on the first page after login](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21548)

Edit 1:

subscribe works, but it is executed after knockout.

```
var customer = customerData.get('customer');
customer.subscribe(function (customer) {
    console.log(customer.firstname);
}, this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer. I'm not sure what I was expecting. 
I wanted the process in ko viewmodel to wait for the data to load, but apparently it happens somewhere else under the hood.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/210888/52739