# Magento 2 reload cart page total section

Tags: magento2, cart

I am updating cart quantity with ajax and that is working is fine. But I cannot figure out how to reload the cart total section. I added this code but it is updating mini-cart section. Is there any section defined for that too? Need to update cart total section after ajax response.

```
    var sections = ['cart'];
    customerData.invalidate(sections);
    customerData.reload(sections, true);
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112948/magento-2-how-do-customer-sections-sections-xml-work

Comment: @NavinBhudiya i already added this code it is updating the mini cart section.

Comment: do you found any way !!?

Comment: Did you find a way to refresh the totals block?

Comment: @bramulous see the answer what i did.

Comment: Won't trigger the reload for me unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gh darvishani

It kind of hack i was using estimate shipping so simple js trick work for me.

```
 $("#s_method_flatrate_flatrate").trigger('click');
```