# Flash messages always are empty after call AJAX POST

Tags: magento2, theme, section

I used Full Page cache for my page. After I register newsletter I get flash message "successfully" and its ok

But after I installed some modules, they can ajax POST and the private-cache-content via is invalidate with empty messages so the Flash Message is disappeared.

Example when I call POST ajax, they also call `customer/section/load/?sections=&update_section_id=true&_=1520414104652` and response data is `messages: 
{messages: [], data_id: 1520414104652}`

I read [how customer sections.xml work](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112948/magento-2-how-do-customer-sections-sections-xml-work), and I found on `Magento\Theme\etc\frontend\sections.xml` always update messages with any action

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
<action name="*">
    <section name="messages"/>
</action>
```

So how can i keep my messages?

Thank you!