# Minicart no update with custom add to cart in magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I created my custom module for add a product to my cart, if I use my controller with this form :

```
<form action="http://*********/mycart/cart/add/uenc/*******/product/1/" method="post">
```

My product is in my cart, but minicart is not update, and change page not resolve this problem.

But, if I change my form link with magento controller like this :

```
<form action="http://*********/checkout/cart/add/uenc/*******/product/1/" method="post">
```

It's work fine

In my controller, I have just change this

```
namespace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart
```

to this

```
namespace Test\Mycart\Controller\Cart;
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112948/magento-2-how-do-customer-sections-sections-xml-work

Answer (score 0):

Please try creating a `sections.xml` file in the etc folder of your module and configure it according to your needs 
For Example:

```
<action name="mycart/cart/add">
    <section name="cart"/>
</action>
```

This would reload customer's minicart on each POST request to your controller. Basically, action node indicates controller path and section node defines which client-side content should be updated.

Caches have to be flushed for this change to apply.

For a reference

> Magento/Checkout/etc/frontend/sections.xml