# Magento 2 :What is the different between invalidate and reload if they both update the sections?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, customer-data, section

If some section should be updated then `customerData.invalidate(sections)`

if you sure, that you really need update some section you can always do something like this: `customerData.reload(['cart'], false)`

This is taken from the answer [Magento 2: how do customer sections / sections.xml work?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112948/magento-2-how-do-customer-sections-sections-xml-work)

What is the different between **invalidate** and **reload** if they both update the sections?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find much difference between invalidate and reload other than that invalidate triggers **customer-data-invalidate**

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js @
>   line 338

```
invalidate: function (sectionNames) {
            var sectionDataIds,
                sectionsNamesForInvalidation;

            sectionsNamesForInvalidation = _.contains(sectionNames, '*') ? buffer.keys() : sectionNames;
            $(document).trigger('customer-data-invalidate', [sectionsNamesForInvalidation]);
            buffer.remove(sectionsNamesForInvalidation);
            sectionDataIds = $.cookieStorage.get('section_data_ids') || {};

            // Invalidate section in cookie (increase version of section with 1000)
            _.each(sectionsNamesForInvalidation, function (sectionName) {
                if (!sectionConfig.isClientSideSection(sectionName)) {
                    sectionDataIds[sectionName] += 1000;
                }
            });
            $.cookieStorage.set('section_data_ids', sectionDataIds);
        },
```

and reload triggers **customer-data-reload**

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js @
>   line 328

```
reload: function (sectionNames, updateSectionId) {
            return dataProvider.getFromServer(sectionNames, updateSectionId).done(function (sections) {
                $(document).trigger('customer-data-reload', [sectionNames]);
                buffer.update(sections);
            });
        },
```

However, both of them do the same thing i.e clear localstorage but it seems they clear different things in local storage.

For invalidate (customer-data-invalidate) following code is called ;

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/product/storage/data-storage.js
>   @line 72

```
initCustomerDataReloadListener: function () {
            $(document).on('customer-data-invalidate', this._flushProductStorage.bind(this));

            return this;
        }
```

which ultimately calls

```
_flushProductStorage: function (event, sections) {
            if (_.isEmpty(sections) || _.contains(sections, 'product_data_storage')) {
                this.localStorage.removeAll();
            }
        },
```

same as reload (customer-data-reload)

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/product/storage/ids-storage.js
>   @line 82

```
initCustomerDataReloadListener: function () {
            $(document).on('customer-data-reload', function (event, sections) {
                if ((_.isEmpty(sections) || _.contains(sections, this.namespace)) && ~~this.allowToSendRequest) {
                    this.localStorage.removeAll();
                    this.data();
                }
            }.bind(this));

            return this;
        },
```