# In CRUD, Why delete item operation is preferred via POST request rather than GET request?

Tags: magento2, php, http-request

Is there is any special security advantages of using a POST request over GET request for delete operation?

As Magento 2 has preferred POST for delete operation.

Answer (score 1):

As per the CRUD Operations, we use GET request to Read information with the request

You can have a reference [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/api/crud)

And for Create or Update Request we use POST Requests

That's why while deletion we use `POST` or `DELETE` request.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the information already stated, on magento 2 POST and PUT requests are tracked in order to invalidate customer private content sections as can be seen in the file

`vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/section-‌​config.js`

```
$(document).on('submit', function (event) { 
    var sections; 
    if (event.target.method.match(/post|put/i)) { 
        sections = sectionConfig.getAffectedSections(event.target.action);
        if (sections) { 
            customerData.invalidate(sections); 
        } 
    } 
});
```

see [Magento 2: how do customer sections / sections.xml work?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112948/magento-2-how-do-customer-sections-sections-xml-work)